# How to use sublime text 2 and Ctags for erlang source code?

Tags: erlang, sublimetext2, ctags

I install the Ctags by package control.
And I also use the sublime-erlang.
Most of the time it works well.
But sometimes I could want to see how it implement in erlang stdlib
It's this possible to jump into stdlib？
And how？

Comment: Sorry I have no answer, but I tested sublime-erlang and it looks cool :o)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the settings which make it possible are slightly covered on the [CTags plugin homepage](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags).

Consider your erlang installation is located at `/usr/lib/erlang` as it usually does, then do the following:

1. Cd into your project or workspace directory, which is better for you.
2. Feed into the shell:

   ```
   ctags --languages=erlang --erlang-kinds=-dr -R -f .libtags \
   /usr/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-*/src \
   /usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-*/src
   ```

   ... and so on for all the otp applications you are interested in.

   It is important to specify *absolute* paths.
3. Open your project specific settings in the Sublime Text (usually `$PROJECT.sublime-project`, if it does not exists, would be better to create one through `Project > Save Project As...`).
4. Append to the `settings` section file path to the `.libtags` we have created before. On my machine that file most of the time looks like this:

   ```
   {
       "folders":
       [
           {
               "path": "/home/keynslug/workspace/projectname",
               "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.beam", "*.app", ".tags*"]
           }
       ],
       "settings": {
           "ctags_extra_tag_files": [
               "/home/keynslug/workspace/.libtags"
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
5. Save and rebuild ctags.

Then if everything went well you would be able to dig into library function definitions as usual.